# Orphaned Page Checker

Tags: orphans

Hey guys I have a large website I am trying to clean out; there are a ton of pages and quite a few of them are orphaned. (a page with no pages that link to it, IE, a page that can't be gotten to).

Is there an online service or a program that will find orphaned pages?

Comment: Not an answer, but the term you are looking for is "Orphaned" pages. That terminology may help your search. Might not too. ;)

Comment: There are tools that will compare your web site against the file system and show the orphans (and lots of other data).  The name of  the one I once used escapes me...

Comment: For comparing, maybe: `wget -P reachable --mirror --page-requisites site` and `diff -qr reachable htdocs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Macromedia Dreamweaver's Site Report > Check Links > Orphan Pages as well as online free service http://www.dead-links.com/ .

I also used unix grep to double check a few randomly.

Comment: If I'd seen this question when it was first posted I would have suggested the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what web server you are running, but here is a link to a similar question with some answers specific to IIS:
[Is there an easy way to generate a report on "dead" files in IIS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/37750/is-there-an-easy-way-to-generate-a-report-on-dead-files-in-iis)